# Rewrite block issue of magento

Tags: php, magento

```
<blocks>
      <slider>
        <class>Magehouse_Slider_Block</class>
      </slider>
      <catalog>
        **<rewrite>
          <layer_filter_price>Magehouse_Slider_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price</layer_filter_price>
        </rewrite>**
      </catalog>
    </blocks>
```

My magento does not calling rewrite block code, same code working on another magento but here that price.php file does not calling, why this is happening please anyone tell me.
path is correct.

Comment: Have you confirmed your module is active?  Also are the ** just to point out where the code is above?

Comment: ** is used to point out where is problem, and yes module also active

Comment: and flushed all the cache?

Comment: there may be a rewrite conflict

Comment: Yes I have deleted all cache, same code executing on another fresh magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a php file with the below, put it in the Magento root and call it in a browser.  This will confirm Magento is recognising the rewrite and if there is nothing else conflicting with it;

```
include_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::init();
echo '<pre>';
print_r(Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->xpath('//global//rewrite'));
echo '</pre>';
```

This will enable you to confirm whether it is attemtping to load your code, and if it is, perhaps the path is wrong.

EDIT EDIT EDIT

Since we spoke at lengths on chat, here are conclusions;

This is not a rewrite issue.

In order to work, the catalog/layer/view.phtml file needs to be loaded to the page.  If layered nav isnt loading on your category template, set the categories to 'is anchor = yes' to autoload it (in most templates).  Or add layered nav to non anchor categories in the xml.

This extension is also not recommended for Magento 1.9 and judging by the comments on their extension page, you are not alone in having issues with it's functionality.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magehouse-free-ajax-layered-navigation-toolbar-with-price-slider-2-2-0.html

Comment: Can you please tell me, where should i add this?

Comment: in the root directory of your Magento installation - same level as the app and skin directories

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [layer] => Magehouse_Slider_Model_Catalog_Layer
        )

    [1] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [layer] => Magehouse_Slider_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer
        )
     [7] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [layer_filter_price] => Magehouse_Slider_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price
        )

Comment: I have get this result

Comment: Ok so it's reading the config correctly, can you confirm the file in your module exists; Magehouse/Slider/Block/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price.php

Comment: Yes, path is correct and also there is no issue of capital and small letter.

Comment: class Magehouse_Slider_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price 
{
     echo "ravi";
 public $_currentCategory;
 public $_searchSession;
 public $_productCollection;
 public $_maxPrice;
 public $_minPrice;
 public $_currMinPrice;
 public $_currMaxPrice;
 public $_imagePath;

...
...
...
}

Comment: There is no content issue, i am again saying same code working on another magento, here also it is adding layout file, template file only having problem with price.php, because i checked config file not calling that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66027/discussion-between-pixiemedia-and-ravi-mule).

Comment: Thank you #PixieMedia, Its an jquery conflict issue :)